# C++ DLL linker error

Tags: c++, api, class, dll, linker

I want to write a dll for an api of a device. since i am new to dlls i wanted to implement it on a simple text editor and then make one for the api.
I have made header file and cpp file but when i run the code i get error lnk2001 followed by lnk1120 which is unresolved external error.

I really have no idea where did i make a mistake, as far as i see i did it the right way. i was wondering if you guys could help me out. tnx.

here is my header file

```
// EditFuncsDll.h
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

namespace EditFuncs
{
    class MyEditFuncs
{
private:
    static std::vector<std::string> MyTextBox;

public:
    static __declspec(dllexport) void Load(std::string command);
    static __declspec(dllexport) void Save(std::string command);
    static __declspec(dllexport) int Lines();
    static __declspec(dllexport) void Add(std::string command);
    static __declspec(dllexport) void Remove(std::string command);
    static __declspec(dllexport) void Insert(std::string command);
    static __declspec(dllexport) int wc(std::string command);
    static __declspec(dllexport) void GetInfo();
};
}
```

and in my cpp file i just define the functions i declared in header file.

and these are the errors i get

> Error 25 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static class std::vector,class std::allocator >,class std::allocator,class std::allocator > > > EditFuncs::MyEditFuncs::MyTextBox" (?MyTextBox@MyEditFuncs@EditFuncs@@0V?$vector@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V?$allocator@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@@std@@A)  C:\Users\Lucy\Desktop\Erfan\Text_Editor_DLL\Text_Editor_DLL\EditFuncsDll.obj    Text_Editor_DLL

and

> Error 26  error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   C:\Users\Lucy\Desktop\Erfan\Text_Editor_DLL\Debug\Text_Editor_DLL.dll   Text_Editor_DLL

Comment: @Assem but I am just defining the functions in the cpp file this is the cpp file of the header not the main cpp. i dont think i should define it there. should i?

Comment: you should define every static member variable declared in the corresponding cpp.
Just write it before the definition of your functions in the .cpp file. 
BTW, I should fix what I wrote in the previous comment :
std::vector EditFuncs::MyEditFuncs::MyTextBox;

Comment: @Assem
here is part of my cpp
'// EditFuncsDll.cpp
#include "EditFuncsDll.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

namespace EditFuncs
{
 static std::vector<std::string> MyTextBox;
 void MyEditFuncs::Load(string command)
 {
  string filename;
  // The name of the file starts at the fifth character of the command and goes to the end
  filename = command.substr(5,command.size());
  ifstream inFile;
  inFile.open(filename);'
so according to what you said i added the definition of that static variable, but still i get the same error. i don know why!

Comment: remove the word "static" in your .cpp before std::vector<std::string> MyTextBox;

Comment: @Assem did it. still not working

Comment: see the modification in answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The head of your cpp should be like this :

```
    #include "EditFuncsDll.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
 using namespace std;
 namespace EditFuncs 
 { 
     std::vector<std::string> EditFuncs::MyEditFuncs::MyTextBox;  
     void MyEditFuncs::Load(string command) 
     { 
        string filename; // The name of the file starts at the fifth character of the command and goes to the end 
        filename = command.substr(5,command.size()); 
        ifstream inFile;
        inFile.open(filename);
        .
        .
        .
```

Comment: OMG its working :D thank you. so whenever i define a static member, i should define it in the corresponding cpp as well. right? thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In your DLL's header file you may want to use a preprocessor macro, that expands to `__declspec(dllimport)` for DLL clients, and to `__declspec(dllexport)` for code that is implementing the DLL (i.e. your DLL .cpp files).

```
// EditFuncsDll.h

#ifdef EDIT_FUNCS_DLL_IMPLEMENTATION
#define EDIT_FUNCS_DLL __declspec(dllexport) // for DLL implementation
#else
#define EDIT_FUNCS_DLL __declspec(dllimport) // for clients
#endif

class EDIT_FUNCS_DLL MyEditFuncs
{
...
};
```

In your DLL's source .cpp file(s), you can `#define EDIT_FUNCS_DLL_IMPLEMENTATION` before #including your DLL header:

```
// EditFuncsDll.cpp

#define EDIT_FUNCS_DLL_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "EditFuncsDll.h"

// ... implementation code
```

Comment: Thanks, actually I am not sure, what exactly dllimport does. I have used msdn as my tutorial for dll, and sometimes it's not clear why and when should i use it. I am looking for a good tutorial about dll but have not found it. and by the way, the code builds successfully now but when I run it, as the functions of the dll return, the program crashes and i do not understand why???!!! can it be from these preprocessor macros?

Comment: @Erfan: I'd suggest these articles from CodeProject: [Regular DLL Tutor For Beginners](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6351/Regular-DLL-Tutor-For-Beginners) and [HowTo: Export C++ classes from a DLL](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28969/HowTo-Export-C-classes-from-a-DLL). Causes of crashes can be different... you may want to give more details (e.g. are you building both the EXE and the DLL with the same VC++ compiler and same CRT flavour?).

Comment: Yes I'm using VS2011 to build the DLL and the .exe. I am making an API for a device. Thank you very much for the links, I just could not find any interesting tutorials. It was either too old or just a Hello World DLL.